# Passing state vs using context in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was exploring useContext react hook by going through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMKvyLRWo0)

In this video, what they have done is basically create a context

context.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const CustomerContext = createContext(null);
```

And pass those context to child component

```
import Table from "./components/table";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CustomerContext } from "./context";
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <p> Hello World</p>
      <CustomerContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Table />
      </CustomerContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And then in the child component access the value or change the value

```
import { CustomerContext } from "./../context";
import React, { useContext } from "react";

const Table = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(CustomerContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={() => setUser("Rohit")}>Current User: {user}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

This could've also been achieved by simply passing the state as props to the child component.

So what is the advantage of using useContext? or maybe I misunderstood the video.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: when the child is nested a few parents in from your `App` component using the context is nice because you dont have to go through each component remembering to pass the props around. you just access it where you need to

Comment: That's the only advantage?

Comment: No, there are other advantages, but you should read the docs to do a deep comparison of pros vs cons. This is a common use case which is why I brought it up. Generally its a much more robust way of dealing with data in your application.

Answer (score 2):

It avoid prop drilling. Passing data through props when you have 4 or 5 nested components is awful, and that's just a small case. Context will allow you to get your data from wherever you want in your application, but also provide a good way to manage it with other method like `dispatch` or `useReducer`.

Also, the ContextApi provided by React allow you to create multiple context to separate your concern which is pretty cool I think when you have a lot of data.